# delete first 5 lines and last 2 lines from txt

Tags: windows, batch-file

Need to delete the first 5 lines and the last 2 lines of a txt file using a bat, been trying with a script that works on win 10 but not on win server 2012 r2.

Any idea why?

heres the script, i have

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "FileToModify=getdoc.txt"
 if not exist "%FileToModify%" goto:leavenow

 set "TempFile=%TEMP%\FileUpdate.txt"
 if exist "%TempFile%" del "%TempFile%"
 if exist newFile.txt del newFile.txt
 if exist Testfinal.txt del Testfinal.txt
 if exist Test1.txt del Test1.txt
 if exist myOriginalFile.txt del myOriginalFile.txt

set "Line=0"
for /F "useback delims=" %%L in ("%FileToModify%") do (
if !Line! GTR 4 (
    echo %%L>>"%TempFile%"
) else (
    set /A Line+=1
    if !Line! GTR 4 echo %%L>>"%TempFile%"
)
)
copy /Y "%TempFile%" "%FileToModify%" >nul

set row=
  for /F "delims=" %%j in (%FileToModify%) do (
if  defined row echo.!row!>>Test1.txt
set row=%%j
   )

set row=
for /F "delims=" %%j in (Test1.txt) do (
 if  defined row echo.!row!> Testfinal.txt
 set row=%%j
   )

 echo { > newFile.txt
 type %FileToModify% >> newFile.txt
 type newFile.txt > getdoc.txt

 del FileUpdate.txt
 del newFile.txt
 del Testfinal.txt
 del Test1.txt

 :leavenow
 echo no file to clean!!!!
 pause
 exit
```

Ps- im sure there is a simple way to do this thanks

Comment: Without even looking at your script, I find it hard to believe it works on Windows 10 but not Windows 2012 Server.

Comment: @Squashman thats my thought too, but iv tested the same file and in win10 it works fine and in win server it breaks when he cant create the test1.txt file

Comment: Does the user have permission to create the test1.txt file on Server 2012? Add some error checking.

Comment: I do not have any issues running your code on any version of Windows.  But your code does not do what you say it does. I tested with 9 lines in a file.  My output was a left curly brace on the first line and lines 5 through 9 after that.

Comment: @Squashman your right i forgot to say that in the end it add { to the first line :s

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the following commented batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "FileToModify=getdoc.txt"
if not exist "%FileToModify%" (
    set "ErrorMessage=No file "%FileToModify%" to clean"
    goto ErrorOutput
)

rem Get number of lines in file to modify by searching with FINDSTR for begin
rem of line which is true for every line in the file. Output by FINDSTR is the
rem line number a colon and the line itself for each line in file. For interest
rem is here just the line number left to first colon from last output line.

for /F "delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /R "^" "%FileToModify%"') do set "LastLineNumber=%%I"

rem Has the file at least 8 lines to remove five lines at top and two
rem lines at bottom and have finally a file with at least one line?

if %LastLineNumber% LSS 8 (
    set "ErrorMessage=File "%FileToModify%" has less than 8 lines"
    goto ErrorOutput
)

rem Decrement the number of last line because the
rem last two lines should be removed from the file.

set /A LastLineNumber-=1

rem Derive name of temporary file to create in folder for temporary files
rem from name of file to modify by replacing its file extension by "tmp".

for %%I in ("%FileToModify%") do set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%%~nI.tmp"

rem Make sure the temporary file does not already exist from a previous
rem run of this batch file broke during processing by command interpreter.
del "%TempFile%" 2>nul

for /F "skip=5 tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /R "^" "%FileToModify%"') do (
    if %%I == %LastLineNumber% goto ReplaceFile
    echo/%%J>>"%TempFile%"
)

:ReplaceFile
move /Y "%TempFile%" "%FileToModify%" 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    del "%TempFile%"
    set "ErrorMessage=File "%FileToModify%" is write-protected"
    goto ErrorOutput
)
endlocal
exit /B

:ErrorOutput
cls
echo %~f0
echo/
echo Error: %ErrorMessage%.
echo/
pause
```

**Note:** This batch file does not produce the right output for a file containing **lines starting with 1 or more `:`** because on second **FOR** option `delims=:` is used which results in splitting up such lines in line number output by **FINDSTR** assigned to loop variable `I` and everything after 1 or more colons assigned to loop variable `J` being the next character in ASCII table after specified loop variable `I`.

But this batch file handles files containing command line critical characters like `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~|<> `` well.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~f0` (name of batch file with file extension and full path).
- `cls /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) to understand why `echo/` is used instead of `echo.` in batch file.

Comment: i think the problem is that i cant write to test1.txt.  any way to go arround this since i dont have administrator permission here?

Comment: @user7963954 The batch code posted by me does not contain `Test1.txt` and so I do not really know what you mean. The file `getdoc.txt` must be in current directory which can be the same directory as the batch file, but can be of course any other directory. And the used account must have write permissions to modify (overwrite) this file. But neither current directory nor user permission issues are in my opinion related to the batch code written by me for this task. They could be the reason for why your code is not working on one machine, but then your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I tried your code, i meant getdoc.txt, with you code i could see the error message File getdoc.txt is write-protected. io can write, create and delete, change, everything but with cmd i get that message

Comment: @razstec Do you have opened the file `getdoc.txt` in an application while running the command prompt? This could cause a sharing violation when the application opened the file with a write lock, i.e. no other application or process including command process can modify the file as long as being opened in the application.

Comment: Hi, no get doc is generated by batch and is not opened when this runs

Comment: @razstec Download and extract to any temporary folder free tool [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) of Sysinternals (Microsoft). Start *Process Monitor* as administrator and set as filter: __Path ends with getdoc.txt__ then __Include__, click on button __Add__ and next on __OK__. Run the batch file which fails to overwrite `getdoc.txt`. Switch back to Process Monitor, stop capturing with Ctrl+E, disable from last 5 buttons in toolbar all except the file system activity button and look on the log from top to bottom. The batch file works on my PC.